# Make change directory and allow parallel jobs at one fails

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I'm using the `make` command to build my C files in Linux. I can build it without errors from another directory using the `-C DIRECTORY` option. I can build it in its directory allowing multiple jobs using `-j [N]`. But when I try to build if from another directory with multiple jobs `make -C DIRECTORY  -j [N]` it fails with: `gcc: error: some_file: No such file or directory`

How can I enforce `make` to change directory and build with multiple jobs together?

Comment: Would it be post your makefile; Looks like some_file is missing; either due to parallelization or clarical error in your makefile. would be able to assist if you could post your makefile

Comment: As @choppe says, please post a [mre]. `-C` and `-j` work fine together so there must be a problem with your specific Makefile.